# Exporting R shiny output to multiple sheets single excel.

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have built an app which gives an output data table based on the filter selected.
Suppose I change the filter 10 times and it gives me 10 results. 
I need to store the results in 10 sheets in single excel.

For example:
Select filter option: A
Get the Output: Output1
Click on Download button.
Save results as sheetname: test1, excel: sample1.xlsx

Now I  Select filter option: B
Get the Output: Output1
Click on Download button.
Save results as sheetname: test2, excel: sample1.xlsx

This is my code

```
output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
         filename = function() 
             {  paste('Sample','_', Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep="") }, 
                content = function(file) {
                write.xlsx(makeTable(), file, sheetName =input$sampleselect, row.names = FALSE , append = TRUE)
             })
```

sampleselect is the filter selection and I am also passing this as the sheet name.

currently, this code throws out unique Excel files.
i.e For filter A: it creates an Excel Sample.xlsx and for filter B: it creates an Excel also named Sample.xlsx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not sure i fully understand your expected output. You would like to update the same excel file and for each selection you would add a sheet. In case the sheet exists already, you would overwrite it? Anyway, pls provide a full app to simplify helping.,..

Comment: I don't think it's possible for a webapp to edit a file once you've downloaded it. So you're going to have to rethink your approach- have a "Save" button instead of a "Download" button, and store the current results in some kind of list in your R code. Then when people click a "Download saved results" button, export a single file.

Comment: @Marius That's a good tip, I will give it a whirl and see how it goes. Thanks.